# What’s the best way to pull specific data values into a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I’m working on a query that’s using a lot of tables. Some of the values I’m trying to capture are going to require some additional work on my part.

I have my basic fields I’m capturing, which are coming directly from the tables. Easy. However, some of the fields I need require additional coding.

For example, I need to find the amount of money paid by a customer for a particular product. Therefore, I’ll need to add the product type name into my WHERE statement for each of these fields.

I know I can use subqueries for each of these, but I’m going to need to join at least 4 different tables on each of these subqueries then add 2 WHERE statements: one to link the data to the main query and another to specifically choose the product I want to select.

**My question is what’s the best way to do this, performance-wise? Should I do a bunch of sub queries or is it better to use a temp table for each product then at the end of the query use left joins to bring it all together?**

*I’m sorry I don’t have any code to post for this question. I don’t have access to my computer right now.*

Comment: I think you need to show us some code and/or data to help explain your question better.

Comment: Impossible to provide definite answer to such a generic question - I suggest you use execution plans to aid your performance decisions

Comment: More information is required, but as a general answer I suspect you are thinking the wrong way - for example your statement `product type name into my WHERE statement for each of these fields` sounds wrong - you would have a set of columns, and where clauses either at the end of the query or as part of join clauses. Also I doubt you need a lot of sub-queries, but should add as many joins as you need in the main query. Give us some sample queries or data and you will get a better answer.

Comment: @TomC I realized after writing the post that without the code, it’s going to be impossible to get an answer for this. I’ll post the code tomorrow. I know I can just put the product type names into my main where clause. This is going to return a different row for each of these product types. I’m looking to put everything into a single row, which is the context for me wanting to use subqueries for each product type name —if I use a subquery for each product type name, I can put them all in the same row (the row is customer based).

Comment: In that case, it *sounds* like you want to have a single query, but simply use case statements in each column, something like `sum(case when producttype='shoes' then salesamount else 0 end) as ShoeValue` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample query that I *think* answers what you want to do, following some of the comments, and based on purely made up tables:

```
select customerid, customername, 
    sum(case when producttype='shoes' then salesvalue else 0 end) as ShoeValue,
    sum(case when producttype='tshirt' then salesvalue else 0 end) as TShirtValue
from customer
join sales on sales.customerid=customer.customerid
group by customerid, customername
```